# Finding matching dictionary pairs within a list and checking the key values to append to a new dictionary

Tags: python

I need to match up dict pairs in the list based on their ref: calculate the pair's delivery time ('delivery' – 'pickup') and route taken and add these to the empty dictionary.
How do I go about this? I have tried iterating through every element in the list based on ref and tried to form multiple lists but it does not seem to work.

Example:
For example if delivery time by "Star" on route 1 with reference 1 was 6 then `data[1]["Star"][1]`
should store the value 6.

Routes (location):

A + B or B + A = Route 1

A + C or C + A = Route 2

B + C or C + B = Route 3

```
data = {1: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}},
        2: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}},
        3: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}}}
```

```
[{'provider': 'Queen', 'ref': 0, 'location': 'B', 'time': 911, 'type': 'pickup'},
 {'provider': 'Star', 'ref': 1, 'location': 'B', 'time': 912, 'type': 'pickup'},
 {'provider': 'Queen', 'ref': 0, 'location': 'A', 'time': 913, 'type': 'delivery'},
 {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 3, 'location': 'B', 'time': 914, 'type': 'pickup'},
 {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 4, 'location': 'C', 'time': 915, 'type': 'pickup'},
 {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 3, 'location': 'C', 'time': 916, 'type': 'delivery'},
 {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 4, 'location': 'A', 'time': 917, 'type': 'delivery',
 {'provider': 'Star', 'ref': 1, 'location': 'A', 'time': 918, 'type': 'delivery'}]
```

If successfully matched, the data should look like this:

```
data = {1: {"Queen": {0: 2}, "Star": {1: 6}, "Trim":{}}, 
    2: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{4: 2}}, 
    3: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{3: 2}}}
```

And if I were to carry out:

```
print(data[1]["Star"][1])
```

the output should be 6.

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
a = 0
for i in list[a:len(list)]:
for j in list[a+1:len(list)]:
    a += 1
    if i['ref'] == j['ref']:
        t = j['time'] - i['time']
        re = i['ref'] 

        if i['location'] == 'A' or 'B' and j['location'] == 'A' or 'B':
            r = 1
        elif i['location'] == 'A' or 'C' and j['location'] == 'A' or 'C':
            r = 2
        else: 
            r = 3

            if i['provider'] == 'Queen':
                p = 'Queen' 
            elif i['provider'] == 'Star':
                p = 'Star' 
            else:
                p = 'Trim' 

                data[r][p][re] = t
                
print(data[2]['Trim'][4])
```

The list refers to the output above containing the list of dictionaries. However, if I try to access the value I only get a key error.

Comment: put your attempt alongside the question, itself.

Comment: It doesn't look like your output is a valid list of dictionaries.   Could you double check it and post again?  Also, using `from pprint import pprint;pprint(data)` makes things more readable.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your data structure seems a bit weird to me. Is it just the delta time between pickup and delivery?

Comment: I'm trying to match up the dictionaries in the lowest block of output based on their 'ref' values, eg. ref 0 location B would be matched to ref 0 location A, and once I have found the pairs, I need to calculate the delivery time (obtained by difference in 'time') and the route they belong to (based on location) and then I need to add these to the data structure. So for a pair belonging to route 2, I want to add it to the key 2 in data, and then based on the provider, I want to add the ref which would store the key value of the delivery  time if that makes sense.

Comment: I *think* you want the 'ref' values to map to the keys in 'data' except that there are 5 different 'ref' values. Also, this example has 3 different providers. Could there be more? Please give an example of what you'd want the dictionary keyed by "Queen" (for example) to look like after parsing the list in the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pretty close. I got it to work with the following code:

```py
from pprint import pp

input_data = [{'provider': 'Queen', 'ref': 0, 'location': 'B', 'time': 911, 'type': 'pickup'}, {'provider': 'Star', 'ref': 1, 'location': 'B', 'time': 912, 'type': 'pickup'}, {'provider': 'Queen', 'ref': 0, 'location': 'A', 'time': 913, 'type': 'delivery'}, {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 3, 'location': 'B', 'time': 914, 'type': 'pickup'}, {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 4, 'location': 'C', 'time': 915, 'type': 'pickup'}, {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 3, 'location': 'C', 'time': 916, 'type': 'delivery'}, {'provider': 'Trim', 'ref': 4, 'location': 'A', 'time': 917, 'type': 'delivery'}, {'provider': 'Star', 'ref': 1, 'location': 'A', 'time': 918, 'type': 'delivery'}]
data = {1: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}}, 2: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}}, 3: {"Queen": {}, "Star": {}, "Trim":{}}}

# Create lists filtered by pickups and deliveries
pickups = [item for item in input_data if item['type'] == "pickup"]
deliveries = [item for item in input_data if item['type'] == "delivery"]

for deliv in deliveries:
    # Get corresponding pickup
    pickup = next(item for item in pickups if item['provider'] == deliv['provider'] and item['ref'] == deliv['ref'])
    delta = deliv['time'] - pickup['time']

    # Determine route by looking at the locations
    location = "".join(sorted([deliv['location'], pickup['location']]))
    if location == "AB":
        route = 1
    elif location == "AC":
        route = 2
    elif location == "BC":
        route = 3

    data[route][deliv['provider']][deliv['ref']] = delta

pp(data)

# Output:
# {1: {'Queen': {0: 2}, 'Star': {1: 6}, 'Trim': {}},
#  2: {'Queen': {}, 'Star': {}, 'Trim': {4: 2}},
#  3: {'Queen': {}, 'Star': {}, 'Trim': {3: 2}}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The code works for me now. If I may ask, do you know what went wrong with my own attempt of coding it?

Comment: No worries. For me your code runs through and prints `2`. But you should **never** name your array `list` because this is a built-in function. Furthermore, you forgot a curly brace in your input list and a line intend at the second for-loop.